# Cannot load a static file

Tags: django, static

I cannot load files from static-folder “todo.js”.

**My project-tree and settings.py:**

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>to do</title>
    {% load static %}
</head>
<body>

 <script src="{% static 'js/todo.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and console gives me the following

```
[21/Aug/2017 16:36:15] "GET /static/js/todo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1643
```

Comment: try with `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), '/path/to/env/swotproject/static')`, and change `{% load static %}` to `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: Great thanks! It's worked. But where can I find any source to read about what has chanhed? (static -> staticfiles and about the path)

Answer (score 0):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` can work, but I suggest you to use `STATICFILES_FINDERS` instead in your `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Then, move your `js` directory inside a new one called `todoRest` (the same way you did it with the templates):

```
static
  \- todoRest  <- this is the new directory
       \- js
           \- todo.js
```

hope this helps!